# Displaying background image dynamically from database in twig

Tags: laravel, twig

I am using laravel and trying to make it possible for users to change the background image of their page using an update form. They upload a pic and the pic is displayed using twig. My code below for getting the user image used for the background pic

```
$this['userprofile'] = User::with('background_pic')->where('id', $slug)->first();
```

The background pic is to be rendered in a div using the code below

```
<div align="center" style="height: 30px; background-image: url('{{ userprofile.avater.path }}');"></d>
```

the image uploads fine to the backend but not sure how to display it in twig. using the above `background-image: url('{{ userprofile.avater.path}}')` does not work

Comment: We need more information to be able to help you with this issue. Can you please share a more complete exempt of the HTML from the template you're using? What's the exact value of `userprofile.user_pic.path`? What's the URI? Are you using Symfony? Did you try `{{ asset(userprofile.user_pic.path) }}` ?

Comment: The solution in your comment worked. I was just trying to be specific

Comment: Thanks for your edit to the question. It clarifies the situation. Glad to hear my comment helped you fix your issue. I've posted the comment as an answer and re-opened the question. Feel free to accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to render the `background-image` url from a variable you need to use the `asset` function.

This twig function resolves the path of your image to a publicly accessible URL.

Example usage:

```
<div style="background-image: url('{{ asset(userprofile.avater.path) }}');"></d>
```